# Find a form's progress on submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, progress

I have a form with many file uploads, the form takes a while to submit. Is there a way with js or jquery or php to get the progress of the form submission?

Comment: Oops, someone downvoted your question: try to write more details or what have you tried to promote this question by upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible since XHR updates coming with HTML5 (client side, pure javascript). Take a look at [XHR updates](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) on html5rocks.com, particularly at [uploading file or blob](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-blob) details: here it goes:

**HTML**

```
<progress min="0" max="100" value="0">0% complete</progress>
```

**JS**

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

  // Listen to the upload progress.
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
      progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
    }
  };

  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

upload(new Blob(['hello world'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
```

Comment: Can you use modernizr or something similar to make sure, browsers not supporting HTML5 don't miss this feature?

Comment: Yes, you definitely should use feature detection to ensure that the current browser you are using supports XHR2.  IE9 and older do not support XHR2.

Comment: @RayNicholus: yes, you are quite right with IE9. Yet I have an alternative solution: let's wait for year or two - and the problem will be solved. It could be solved instantly by writing one line of code, but I am sooo lazy...